# Simulink PID 3 output signals block

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I'm following a Simulink tutorial with PID controller. Where can I find the following block?

[image: PID block]

Comment: Open the Library Browser and type PID into the search box. If it's part of Simulink it should show up. That block could also be a custom block or masked subsystem created by the person who created the tutorial. Your best bet is to contact them.

Comment: It's not part of simulink :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably an old tutorial and that block looks like a user-made subsystem rather than a library block. The PID blocks have gone through a revamp recently and the ones provided in the Simulink library are probably what you need:

- [PID Controller](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html): continuous or discrete, depending on how you parameterise it
- [PID Controller 2 DOF](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller2dof.html): two-degree-of-freedom PID controller, again continuous or discrete depending on how you param